# Entity Framework 6 - Database First - Removing column from model that should still exist in the Db

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have a database table that I have pulled into my edmx.  However, a couple columns I do not want to exist in the model as they are simply for auditing purposes.  The columns are "CreatedOn" and "UpdatedOn" and are simply timestamps of when the table row was created/updated.

The issues is that I can easily remove the 2 columns from the conceptual model, but then if another developer does an "update from database" these columns would be pulled back in.  Is there any way I can force the designer to never pull these files in?  Maybe in the T4 templates somehow?